# Get control which style is applied to from within a control template inside the style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I have a style for a `TextBox` which contains a `ControlTemplate`. The idea is that when a textbox using this style is in error, the `ControlTemplate` is applied to it, and this all works. What I would like to do is preserve the Tooltip of the Textbox which this style is applied to, so that controls inside the `ControlTemplate` can display the same ToolTip when they are interacted with. The issue is that I cannot find a way to get the Control which the style is applied to from inside the style.

I've tried setting the ToolTip for one of the controls inside the ControlTemplate as follows:

`<ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ToolTip}"/>`

But this just gives me a blank ToolTip (I think `TemplatedParent` only works when the ControlTemplate is not inside a style for some reason).

I know I could probably do this manually for each textbox, but I have in excess of 20 textboxes, so that doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do it. I suspect I am misunderstanding something fundamental about how `TemplatedParent` works.

Textbox style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="TextBox"> 
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="TemplateGrid">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Foreground="Red" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE7BA;"
                                       PreviewMouseDown="ExclamationPointMouseDown"
                                       ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ToolTip}">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                  Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                         Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=Tag}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gainsboro" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: You should set the ToolTip directly on the TextBox and not on an element of the ControlTemplate. I wonder why you even override the template in the first place. It's basically empty. If you want to show a red border simply wrap the TextBox into a border. To make it reusable simply create a UserControl that contains a TextBox wrapped into a Border. Did you know that WPF supports validation and automatically provides a visual error feedback (red border by default) that is also customizable? Maybe you should show the related code. It appears to be wrong. It also gives us something to review...

Comment: @BionicCode. The tooltip is set correctly on the textbox, the issue is when you mouse over an element of the template you occasionally lose the tooltip. I'm using the red border already with error validation, however I am using the template to add a red exclamation pointer overlayed on the textbox as well., which the user can click to get information about why the value is incorrect. It was my understanding that this was not possible simply by customising error feedback. I'll attach code for the entire textbox style.

Comment: No, the ToolTip is *not* set correctly on the TextBox. It is set on the internal TextBlock. And you override it with your trigger. Inside the template: a) simply set IsHitTestVisibile to false on the Grid, then b) remove the TextBlock.ToolTip assignment and c) finally remove the Trigger that triggers on HasError==false. Now the ToolTip value is only replaced with the error message when HasError ==true and is automatically reverted to the original value as soon HasError == false evaluates to true.

Comment: @BionicCode. Thanks, I was trying to solve an unnecessary problem of my own creation as usual!